# Фиксированная частота кадров SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть проект для работы с физикой с использованием sfml, но на разных устройствах программа работает по-разному. Как задать фиксированные промежутки времени между обновлениями?

Код:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

const int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Title", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    sf::Clock clock;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float dt = clock.restart().asSeconds();

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        //update
        update(dt);
        //скорость += ускорение * dt
        //позиция += скорость * dt

        window.clear();
        
        //render
        render(window);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Пробовал `window.setFramerateLimit()`, но это ограничивает только максимальную частоту кадров.

Comment: ахахаххах, это зависит от мощности пк

Comment: @Данил, что зависит от мощности пк?

Comment: Мы не можем знать, сколько программа будет отрисовывать кадр и прочее. Нельзя сделать дельту времени прям идеальной. Мы должны это учитывать при написании кода сами. Статья [«Fix Your Time Step»](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/).

Comment: Наоборот, обновление не должно зависеть от промежутков времени или от частоты рисования кадров. По-хорошему, игровая логика, рендеринг и обработка системных событий должны производится асинхронно.

Comment: @a_nR1085__i так кол-во кадров недостаточно большое?

Comment: @ShamusRezol, это я знаю. Я имею в виду, что при большем времени выполнения мы должны запускать update несколько раз, а при меньшем тормозить программу.

Comment: @KoVadim, в том и дело, fps очень большой и не постоянный

Comment: тогда sleep с рассчитанным значением легко поправит ситуацию. То есть, замеряйте, сколько времени ушло на выполнение внутрицикловой логики и в самом конце просто вычитайте и делайте паузу `sleep(1/fps - cycle_time)`. И все будет хорошо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
//DELTA_TIME = 1.0f / 60.0f

window.setFramerateLimit(1.0f / DELTA_TIME);

while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float dt = clock.restart().asSeconds();

        //update
        unsigned int nr = std::ceil(dt / DELTA_TIME);
        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
            update(DELTA_TIME);

        window.clear();
        
        //render
        render(window);

        window.display();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как внутрицикловая логика может выполнятся с разной скоростью, то нужно вручную ее "подкорректировать". Обычно это делается так

```
float want_fps = 50;
while (need_run) {
    int start = getCurrentTime();
    // логика
    //....
    // отрисовка
    //....
    int time_to_sleep = (1.f/want_fps - (stop-start);
    if (time_to_sleep > 0) {
       sleep(time_to_sleep);
    }
}
```

перепишем это на sfml

```
float want_fps = 50;
sf::Clock loop_timer;
while(....) {
   // логика и отрисовка
   // ....
   sf::Int32 frame_duration = loop_timer.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();
   sf::Int32 time_to_sleep = int(1000.f/want_fps) - frame_duration;
   if (time_to_sleep > 0) {
        sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(time_to_sleep));
    }
    loop_timer.restart();
}
```

Comment: прикольно, коммент плюсуется, а ответ с более подробным объяснением - минусуют.